insertUI to create infinite inputs based on previous value
I'm trying to use either insertUI, or a renderUI to create infinite potential inputs for the user. From what I understand, this is easily accomplished by an actionButton, here's an example of using an actionButton: using actionButton + insertUI in R shiny modules to create multiple inputs However, I haven't seen the usage in open field inputs like text/numeric. When I try to create instances based on a text/numeric input, I seem to always create duplicates with either insertUI or renderUI.

My code will use a module for the UI to create a numericInput.
Then I use a second module for the Server to create an
observeEvent that checks the number in the input. If the number exists and
is over 10, then it will insertUI using the UI module.
In the Server, I use an observe to check for the number of inputs, so
it will know how many of the Server modules to create. This is where
I suspect the problem lies, as it tends to create multiple instances of the UI
module. I've been told before it's bad practice to have an observeEvent within an observe, though I'm not sure how else to accomplish this otherwise.

How can I insert only a single UI, rather than multiple UIs?
Code:
library(shiny)

#Modules and functions########################
#UI module to create a numeric input
numericModule <- function(id) { 
  numericInput(inputId = NS(id, "Numeric"), 
               label = paste0(id), 
               value = NA)  
}

#This is my servermodule. If number is above 10, insertUI
numericObserver <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    #For the Numeric input, observeEvent
    observeEvent(input$Numeric, {
      
      #If value exists and is over 10...
      if(!any(is.null(input$Numeric),
             is.na(input$Numeric),
             input$Numeric < 10)) {
        
        #Insert new input after
        insertUI(selector = paste0("#", NS(id, "Numeric")),
                 where = "afterEnd",
                 ui = numericModule(id+1))
        
      }
    })
    
  })
}


#UI ########################

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericModule(1)
)

#SERVER ##########################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Observe the inputs. For each input, create a new servermodule
  #*This is where I believe the problem lies***
  observe({
    
    lapply(1:length(names(input)), function(x) {
      
      numericObserver(x)
      
    })
    
  })
  
}

#RUN SHINY#################
shinyApp(ui, server)


Here a solution to what I think you want to do.
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

numericUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  numericInput(
    inputId = ns("numeric"),
    label = paste0(id),
    value = NA
  )
}

numericServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    debounced_input <- reactive(input$numeric) |> debounce(1000)
    inserted <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

    observe({
      print(paste0("input ", id, ": ", input$numeric))
      
      if (isTruthy(debounced_input()) && debounced_input() > 9 && !inserted()) {
        inserted(TRUE)

        insertUI(
          "#input-container",
          "beforeEnd",
          numericUI(id + 1)
        )
      }
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    id = "input-container",
    numericUI(1)
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    existing_inputs   <- names(input)
    input_numbers     <- str_extract(existing_inputs, "\\d+") |> as.numeric()
    newer_input_index <- max(input_numbers)
    
    numericServer(newer_input_index)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


This is very close! The only issue I'm encountering is when a person types slowly. For example, if I meant to type "100", but I type "10", it evaluates creating the next input, then I add the extra "0", it will create a duplicate input. I tried to mitigate this by adding an if statement of !NS(id+1, "numeric") %in% names(input) into the insertUI area, but that doesn't seem to solve it.

That was out of the scope of your original question. That new problen can be solve with shiny::debounce.

I added the changes. The debounce help you with those cases, feel free to play with the waiting time and adjust it to the user experience you're looking for.

I appreciate your update. Referring to my original post, I want to insert single inputs, rather than multiple. debounce helps with delayed changes, but this code still produces duplicates. Type "10", wait for the debounce evaluation to insert a single input, then add an extra "0", and it will add two more inputs, for a total of three with the same inputID. Any suggestions?

Editted with your new request

Perfect! Thank you! The reactiveVal is a nice solution!
